# How to bundle js files in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-bundling

I have a angular application with lot of js files , how can I bundle all those files.

Every where I see in web , they suggest to use BundleConfig to bundle js files 
but I'm using empty web application template in asp.net .

How to bundle js files in an order so that no conflicts would appear and there would be no problem in picking  absolute paths and relative paths

Answer (score 3):

How about create a new project that is a full MVC project (select MVC as the tempalte not 'empty'. Then look under the App_Start/BundleConfig.cs, create that exact file and register it as the default project does in the global.asax.cs?

global.asax.cs:

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

App_Start/BundleConfig.cs

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

To be honest though. I would use a Node based tool like webpack or gulp to do this. You CAN use bundles but they are not as powerful and you miss out on a lot of things you could do in a front-end build. It would help a lot more in terms of the correct load order for example.

Comment: You CAN use bundles but they are not as powerful and you miss out on a lot of things you could do in a front-end build. For example?

Comment: The ability to use future JavaScript features now, use css pre-processors, linting tools, the list goes on. I think that bundling on the server like this is by now not considered best practice (especially considering the latest .NET core templates use nodejs builds for the javscript)

Answer (score 0):

In common, we have 2 ways to bundle AnguarJS/ASP.NET:

1. use bundle like above post BundleCollection from Justsayno
2. Use compress JS tool like grunt or gulp. Sample. https://github.com/MarlabsInc/webapi-angularjs-spa OR 
   https://github.com/dchill72/NpmBowerGulpSample

Hope it help!