# when implement autocomplete i get issues script on console log?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datatables

I work on asp.net mvc . I face issue when run autocomplete but I don't know how to solve it

when run asp.net MVC application these issues display on console.log of resignation page .

resignation page inherit from layout page `_LayoutResignation` .

errors display on resignation page  as below :

```
jquery-1.5.min.js:16 Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at Function.each (jquery-1.5.min.js:16:10613)
    at t.widget (jquery-ui.min.js:6:4729)
    at jquery-ui.min.js:7:13824
    at jquery-ui.min.js:6:73
    at jquery-ui.min.js:6:84
bootstrap.js:15 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 4
    at bootstrap.js:15:11
    at bootstrap.js:17:2
datatables.min.js:176 Uncaught TypeError: l(...).on is not a function
    at datatables.min.js:176:457
    at datatables.min.js:60:299
    at datatables.min.js:60:326
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js:156 Uncaught TypeError: $form.off is not a function
    at Object.attachValidation (jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js:156:26)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js:249:26)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.5.min.js:16:10828)
    at init.each (jquery-1.5.min.js:16:7403)
    at Object.parse (jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js:246:20)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js:428:28)
    at Object.resolveWith (jquery-1.5.min.js:16:12509)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.5.min.js:16:8628)
    at HTMLDocument.A (jquery-1.5.min.js:16:14342)
RequesterIndex?filenumber=103085:351 Uncaught ReferenceError: searchText is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (RequesterIndex?filenumber=103085:351:41)
    at HTMLInputElement.handle (jquery-1.5.min.js:16:28630)
    at HTMLInputElement.l (jquery-1.5.min.js:16:25280)
```

I have layout page is main page `_LayoutResignation.cshtml`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Resignation Submission Form</title>
    <link href="~/Content/DataTables/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")


    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
     
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

on resignation page I implement auto complete .

All issues for console log display on resignation page console log

```
    @model HR.WorkforceRequisition.Models.ResignationRequester
    
    
    @{
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutResignation.cshtml";
    }
<form id="ResignationApp" >
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"
        language="javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txtLineManagerId").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    var searchText = $("#txtLineManagerId").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetAllEmployeeBasedSearchText", "Resignation")',
                        data: { searchText: searchText },
                        method: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return { label: item.EmployeeID, value: item.EmployeeID, employeeName: item.EmployeeName };
    
                            }))
    
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#LineManagerName").val(ui.item.employeeName);
         
                },
                minLength: 4,
            });
           });
```

so How to solve issues related to jQuery and bootstrap above ?

Note jQuery version run on my application is 3.4.1 .

**Updated answer**

can you tell me please
wrong scripts as below

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"
        language="javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

correct must be as below :

correct scripts will be ???

Comment: thanks for support so what i do to solve these issues please can you tell me exactly modifications and i can provide all details you needed

Answer (score 0):

It's in the error message: `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 4`

Looking at the first line of the error message, it seems your jQuery version is 1.5 (not 3.4.1 like you said): `jquery-1.5.min.js:16 Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read properties...`

This happened because you added multiple jQuery scripts to your `js` bundle. You need to remove the version `1.5` from the bundle. You also made the same mistake for `jquery-ui`.

Check this answer to see how to deal with bundles: [How to bundle js files in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38427776/how-to-bundle-js-files-in-asp-net)

Comment: thanks for support so what i do to solve these issues please can you tell me exactly modifications and i can provide all details you needed

Comment: i updated original post